# What's the difference between StringBuilder and ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, stringbuilder

In an interview, I want to build up a new String with some substrings. I argued that `ArrayList<String>` is almost the same as `StringBuilder`, but the interviewer said I should always use `StringBuilder` if I need to deal with String. I think the time complexity of adding/removing functions between them are the same.

Comment: Did you get the job? A better question should have been, "When should you use a `StringBuilder`, and when would a `List<String>` be better?"

Answer (score 4):

They aren't the same thing at all. `StringBuilder` builds a *single* string, while `ArrayList<String>` is just that--an array of *separate* strings. Of course, you can concatenate all of the array's strings with `String.join("", list)`, where the first argument is the separator that you want to use, but why would you go that route instead of just using the class that was designed to do *exactly* what you're trying to do in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to memory consumption. `String` is an object, while `ArrayList<String>` holds separate objects, `StringBuilder` holds only one.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you continue to need the separate elements you are adding to the list, you should use a StringBuilder.

After all, you can't directly get a concatenated string from the contents of the list: you have to put it in, say, a StringBuilder.

But in the specific case of building up a string of *substrings*, `StringBuilder` provides methods to allow you to append portions of `String`s without using `substring`: the `append(CharSequence, int, int)` method is an optimization to avoid creating that extra string.

---

It should be mentioned that, at least when I have written python, it has been considered better to build up a list, and then use `''.join(theList)` at the end, which is basically the analog of `ArrayList<String>`.

I don't know enough about python to know why this is considered particularly better.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder has a member function to return the whole built string, whereas in ArrayList, you have to concatenate the strings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can "build" strings using both. However `StringBuilder` is a class specializing in building strings with its `append` `insert` `delete` `charAt` etc... methods. An `ArrayList` is a general purpose collection which lacks most of this functionality. Consider implementing the following (contrived example) with an `ArrayList`:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("time: ")
            .append(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .deleteCharAt(4)
            .reverse();

    System.err.println(sb); // 3153067310451 emit
```

Ergonomics and readability aside, there are performance considerations but those are largely irrelevant on trivially sized examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single `String` at the end, performance and memory consumption are some differences for sure. Whenever you build a `String` from parts, in the good case you end up using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), or in a slightly worse case [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html), and in the worst case you end up concatenating two strings, then throw them away, and repeat - lots of allocations and garbage collection in this case.

[JLS12 still mentions `StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) by name for optimization (but hopefully `StringBuilder` is used internally, as *similar technique*):

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate `String` object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the `StringBuffer` class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.

In the particular case of having a `List<String>` and later using `String.join()` on it, `StringJoiner` contains the particular [`StringBuilder`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/StringJoiner.java#l76) object which is going to be used.
So there will be a builder anyway, and then it may be more efficient to use it from the beginning.